# Save the XML returned from the SQL server in xml file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I am using (For XML Auto retrieve all the Table data  from sql server.
 XSLT to style the XML from the server.
I want to save the xml returned from the sql server to xml file inside folder ( folder created problematically as well as the xml file)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strConnenction = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring0034"].ConnectionString;
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    XPathNavigator xpathnav = xd.CreateNavigator();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnenction))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from Employees as products for XML AUTO, ELEMENTS", conn);
        using (XmlWriter xw = xpathnav.PrependChild())
        {
            xw.WriteStartElement("products");
            using (XmlReader xr = command.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                xw.WriteNode(xr, true);
            }
            xw.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    XmlProducts.XPathNavigator = xpathnav;


}
```

}

Thanks you so much for your help

Comment: Did you mean folder created programatically, not problematically? I know for me sometimes it's the same thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any save method being called, your creating the xml alright but not writing to a file
i.e.:

> xd.Save("myxml.xml")

Comment: I tried to add x.Save("myxml.xml"); as the end but it gives me an error when i run it (Access to the path 'C:\Program Files ....\myxml.xml' is denied.)

Comment: when using IIS try adding the Application Pool User to the folder's Permissions